# std::array initialization, for objects without a default ctor?

Tags: c++, initialization

I work on a memory constrained system where new/malloc calls are wrapped to fail at build time. So `std::vector` is not an acceptable solution, unfortunately.

I have an `std::array` member of a class where the size is known at compile time, but may vary between particular targets (e.g. from a config file) so I have access to something like `constexpr size_t len = Config::ArrSize`. I want my class to hold a `std::array` of objects, but these objects they do not have default constructors. I would much prefer to avoid two step initialization (e.g. implement a meaningless default ctor, and then pass them actual values later). I also know all the constructor values at compile time! I just can't find a clean way to convey this, since the *length* might vary between particular targets, but is known for any *given* garget.

Is there a way to cleanly convey this? e.g. I'd want something akin to

```
#include Config.h

constexpr size_t arr_size = Config::ArrSize;
constexpr size_t ctor_arg = Config::Arg;

class Foo {
  public:
  // line which doesn't work but demonstrates what I'd like
  Foo() : fooArr {Bar(ctor_arg)} {}
  private:
  std::array<Bar, arr_size> fooArr;

};
```

They will all be initialized the same way, and have a known size at compile time. They must be constructed upon initialization because of their lack of default ctors. Something like a `std::fill` but available at initialization. Yes I could defer it for a bit with pointers until the ctor body but that's ugly imho. How can I do this?

`Bar` doesn't have a `constexper` ctor but perhaps that might help?

Comment: Is it viable to implement `Foo`'s default constructor in Config.cpp? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbbcba21c164cbdd

Comment: @MooingDuck: The would obviate the question, but good point! Usually better to avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: @MooingDuck yes it is possible in my particular use case, but I think the question should stand for those who don't have the ability to modify the code they may have to use.

Comment: @brenzo: My followup suggestion would be to put `#define CTOR_IMPL {Bar(ctor_arg), Bar(ctor_arg), Bar(ctor_arg)}` in the header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Option 1: Use a named constructor idiom

We'll write a [named constructor idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom), `array_repeat()`, which takes a single value and produces - at compile-time - an array with all values set to it. You can then write:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo() : fooArr {array_repeat<arr_size>(Bar(ctor_arg))} {}
private:
  std::array<Bar, arr_size> fooArr;
};
```

I've split off the implementation into a separate question and answer, [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63821008/1593077).

#### Option 2: Use a vector with a custom allocator

`std::vector` [has](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) an additional template parameter - the allocator class. The default value is an allocator which uses `new[]` and `delete[]`. But - you could have an allocator that takes up a fixed buffer on the stack (or wherever), and use a resizable `std::vector` still. That would save you the need to pre-construct dummy values.

Comment: Just wondering, how did you made the link look like a button?

Comment: @Ranoiaetep: Click the "Edit" button below my post and find out by reading the source!

Comment: Been trying to, keep showing "edit queue is full" :D

Comment: @Ranoiaetep: Try <kbd> and </kbd> within the link brackes.

Comment: Cool! Thank you!

Comment: Option 1 satisfies my needs but it's a little verbose for a simple concept. Not that it's necessarily a *bad* thing but I am a bit surprised this appears to be the cleanest way to resolve this. Option 2 is very interesting and arguably even more obscure, but is probably more readable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Bar(someClass obj) { /*...*/ }
};

class Foo
{
public:
    template<class... T>
    Foo(T... obj) : fooArr {Bar(obj)...} {}
private:
    std::array<Bar, arr_size> fooArr;
}
```

while I don't know if that's the best way of doing it.

Comment: Issue with this is that I believe I'd have to add template annotations to the entire `Foo` class, which is again really messy. :/ e.g. there would be `template<>` statements on the dozen or so methods in the `.cpp` file.

Comment: @brenzo I believe you only need the template for the constructor, since your `std::array` already had a type in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use braces initialization `std::array<int,4> a = {1,2,3,4};`... perhaps you could write a template function that initializes it without directly writing initializer list but I am uncertain how.

Generally, I don't advice using `std::array` when the type isn't default constructible. You could use type like `boost::small_vector` instead that has static capacity and dynamic size.

Comment: We don't use `boost` sadly, and I doubt I could make a case to have it pulled in for such a small change. The brace initialization would work but I can't make it generic for size `N`. I need a way to do this with the standard library afaik.

Comment: @brenzo You can just copy implementation or make something similar. The class isn't complicated by any means.