# How can I construct an std::array filled with some uniform value?

Tags: c++, arrays, stdarray

`std::array` can be constructed (at compile time with newer C++ versions) with specific values, e.g.

```
std::array a{1, 4, 9};
```

however - it does not have a constructor, or a standard-library named constructor idiom, taking a single value and replicating it. i.e. we don't have:

```
std::array<int, 3> a{11};
// a == std::array<int, 3>{11, 11, 11};
```

How can we, therefore, construct an array given just the value to repeat?

**Edit:** I'm looking for a solution which would work even for element types which are not default constructible; so, a solution going through default-constructing the array, then filling it, is not what I'm after - despite the fact that this will work for the case of `int` (like in the example).

Answer (score 8):

We can write an appropriate [named constructor idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-ctor-idiom) to achieve this. Then, your example definition would look like:

```
auto a = array_repeat<3>(11);
// a == std::array<int, 3>{11, 11, 11};
```

The implementation is a bit clunky, however, as we need to use the ["indices trick"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31463388/1593077) that takes a lot of boilerplate in C++11, so let's assume C++14:

```
namespace detail {

template<size_t, class T>
constexpr T&& identity(T&& x) { return std::forward<T>(x); }

template<class T, size_t... Indices>
constexpr auto array_repeat_impl(T&& x, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    return std::experimental::make_array(identity<Indices>(x)...);
}

} // end detail

template<size_t N, class T>
constexpr auto array_repeat(T&& x)
{
    return detail::array_repeat_impl(std::forward<T>(x), std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

See this working on [<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/8n4dMM).

If you can compile your code C++20, you can drop the dependency on `make_array`  and write:

```
namespace detail {

template<size_t, class T>
constexpr T&& identity(T&& x) { return std::forward<T>(x); }

template<class T, size_t... Indices>
constexpr auto array_repeat_impl(T&& x, std::index_sequence<Indices...>)
{
    return std::array{identity<Indices>(x)...};
}

} // end detail

template<size_t N, class T>
constexpr auto array_repeat(T&& x)
{
    return detail::array_repeat_impl(std::forward<T>(x), std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

[<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/dzPPfM)

Notes:

- This solution is somewhat similar to Jared Hoberock's `tuple_repeat`, part of his [tuple utilities for C++11](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/tuple_utility/).
- Thanks goes to @Caleth and @L.F. for pointing out a inappropriate forwarding in `array_repeat_impl`.
- The `array_repert()` function take rvalue references and moves from them, so it's ok to create a temporary in the argument, even if it's expensive.

Comment: Here I was thinking, "Matt has his own button now! W00t w00t!" But no. Just sneaky tagging. I commend the sneaky tagging.

Comment: Not sure I like forwarding x multiple times in `array_repeat_impl`

Comment: @Caleth: So, would you suggest something like `T&& x_ref = std::forward<T>(x)` and using that instead?

Comment: No, just drop the forwarding at the point where you are copying x multiple times `std::array{identity<Indices>(x)...};`

Comment: To support Caleth's comment, currently `array_repeat<3>(std::string{"123"})` results in `["123", "", ""]`.

Comment: @L.F.: You're right. The use of an rvalue reference messes up the value. Fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

With C++20, you can make a helper for this straightforwardly when the type is default-constructible and copyable by using the now-constexpr `fill` function ([live example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aT8xEj)):

```
#include <array>
#include <concepts>
#include <cstddef>

template<std::size_t N, std::semiregular T>
constexpr auto array_repeat(const T& value) -> std::array<T, N> {
    std::array<T, N> ret;
    ret.fill(value);
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    constexpr auto a = array_repeat<3>(11);
    static_assert(a == std::array<int, 3>{11, 11, 11});
}
```

This could potentially be less efficient, but whether that's a problem is up to you.

Comment: Chris, I have to apologize, since I meant to ask about the case where you can't just default-construct-and-fill, and have to construct from the get-go with the repeated value. Perhaps I should also alter the example to reflect that. Again, my apology.

Comment: @einpoklum, It's fine, I suspected this wouldn't be useful to you specifically, but I hope someone will find it useful who didn't otherwise know this was a possibility.